# Proof required of : Polynomials are differentiable everywhere

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

So I tried to answer this question by proving that all polynomials are continuous everywhere but my professor turned it down saying that only the converse is true. So I was left scratching my head a bit. It would be really helpful if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Show that all polynomial terms have no nonnegative exponents and any $x^n$ for nonnegative $n$ is differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial of degree $n$ is the sum of terms of the form $a_kx^k$ where $0\leq k \leq n$, and given the sum rule for derivatives, it suffices to show each such term is differentiable. When $k=0$, $a_kx^k$ is just a constant whose derivative is $0$. When $1\leq k\leq n$, you have $(a_kx^k)'=ka_kx^{k-1}$. If this requires proof, you may use the definition:
$$(a_kx^k)'=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a_k(x+h)^k-a_kx^k}{h} $$
and then expand $(x+h)^k$ according to the binomial theorem. Your goal is to cancel $h$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, not all continuous curves are differentiable; See the Weierstrass function. So, what you have to do is to show that the derivative of any polynomial is defined everywhere.

You should start off with the general formula for the polynomial and find its derivative. That should get you going in the correct direction.